# Store the list of directories in an array

Tags: perl, directory-structure

I received a Perl script which currently reads a list of directories from a text file and stores them in a string vector. I would like to modify it so that it reads the names of all the directories in the current folder, and stores them in the vector. This way, the user doesn't have to modify the input file each time the list of directories in the current folder changes.

I have no knowledge of Perl, apart from the fact that it looks like array indices in Perl start from 0 (as in Python). I have a basic knowledge of bash and Python, but I'd rather not rewrite the script from scratch in Python. It's a long, complex script, and I'm not sure I'd be able to rewrite it in Python. Can you help me? Here is the part of the script which is currently reading the text file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Cwd;
.
.
.
open FILES, "<files.txt" or die; # open input file
<FILES> or die;              # skip a comment
my $nof = <FILES> or die;    # number of directories
<FILES> or die;              # skip a comment
my @massflow;                # read directories
for (my $i = 0; $i < $nof; $i++){
    chomp($massflow[$i] = <FILES>);
}
. 
.
. 
close(FILES);
```

PS I think the script is rather self-explanatory, but just to be sure, this piece opens a text file called "files.txt", skips a line, reads the number of directories, skips another line and reads, one name for each line, the names of all the directories in the current folder, as written in "files.txt".

EDIT I wrote this script following @Sobrique suggestion, but it lists also files, not only dirs:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Cwd;

my @flow = glob ("*");

my $arrSize = @flow;
print $arrSize;
for (my $i = 0; $i < $arrSize; $i++){
    print $flow[$i], "\n";
}
```

Comment: It looks like a very old Perl-script, using what is nowadays considered bad habits combined with Baby perl. (add 'use strict;' and 'use warnings;' at the beginning, for starters. Also the open command is not how we do it nowadays. (See perldoc -f open) The loop to read the file is Baby perl. One should really use a while loop.

Comment: Your code to print the contents of `@flow` is needlessly verbose. It can be replaced with the single statement: `print "$_\n" for @flow;` or (in Perl 5.10+) `say $_ for @flow;`

Comment: @DaveCross Or just `say for @flow`

Comment: @DaveCross, cool, thanks! `perl -v`  gives me back `This is perl, v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi`, thus I'll go with `print "$_\n" for @flow;`

Comment: @HåkonHægland: Thanks. No idea how I missed that!

Comment: @DeltaIV: Perhaps you could use a version of Perl that is less than ten years old.

Comment: @DaveCross perhaps IT  won't bother to update RHEL just for the sake of  `say $_ for @flow;`. And let's not talk about installing it in my home. I already tried that road with `gnuplot` (we're stuck with 4.2), and man, that so didn't work.

Comment: Updating system perl is rarely a good idea. Updating /usr/local/bin/perl can be really handy though.

Comment: Well, there are plenty of other good reasons for using a newer version of Perl :-) And updating from (I guess) RHEL 5.x is a really good idea too.

Comment: @Sobrique, on the system I work, `/usr/local/bin/perl` is just a symbolic link to `/usr/bin/perl`, thus correct me if I'm wrong but I think updating `/usr/local/bin/perl`  would require updating system perl. Anyway, even if that's false, I assure you that when I tried to install `gnuplot` in my home, all Hell broke loose. Apparently even the locations of system libraries are nonstandard on this system, thus I'm only able to compile the simplest of things from source.

Comment: @DaveCross, I agree on both counts, but I'm not in a position to request  updating from RHEL. Even if I requested only a perl update, I'd rather not relive the experience I had with `gnuplot`....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's simpler than you think:

```
my @list_of_files = glob ("/path/to/files/*");
```

If you want to filter by a criteria - like 'is it a directory' you can:

```
my @list_of_dirs = grep { -d } glob "/path/to/dirs/*";
```

Comment: I think the OP needs directories.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the pointer, but it looks like this lists also the files in the current dir, not just the directories. I modified my question to include my test script, because including it in the comments seems complicated.

Comment: `grep` is the tool for that job then. Example updated.

Comment: In case you want directories in your current working directory, including hidden (dot) files: `my @list_of_dirs = grep { -d } glob("* .*")`.

Comment: @Sobrique, just a last question. Is there any difference between `my @list_of_dirs = grep { -d } glob "/path/to/dirs/*";` and `my @list_of_dirs = grep { -d } glob ("/path/to/dirs/*");` ?

Comment: No. They'll work the same. The only time brackets are mandatory is when there's e.g. multiple arguments and the order of precedence is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Open directory inside which the sub-directories are with [`opendir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/opendir.html), read its content with [`readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html).  Filter out everything that is not a directory using file test `-d`, see [`-X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

```
my $rootdir = 'top-level-directory';
opendir my $dh, "$rootdir" or die "Can't open directory $rootdir: $!";
my @dirlist = grep { -d } map { "$rootdir/$_" } readdir ($dh);
```

Since `readdir` returns bare names we need to prepend the path.

Comment: Using `glob()` is easier :-)

Comment: @DaveCross Well, yes, I agree, of course. But I thought that there'd every reason to show the other standard method as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get dir like this:

```
my @dir = `find . -type d`;

perl -e ' use strict; use warnings; use Data::Dumper; my @dir = `find . -type d`; print Dumper(\@dir);'

$VAR1 = [
          '.
',
          './.fonts
',
          './.mozilla
',
          './bin
',
          './.ssh
',
          './scripts
'
        ];
```